# why this code is always producing same result?

Tags: c, memory-address

I just couldn't understand why this code is always giving 5 as output. I am not a pro in C and was trying to understand pointers and addresses in more detail. then I stucked at this code

the code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

int b[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

int n = &b[3] - &a[2];

printf("%d\n", n);

}
```

**As far as my understanding, what we are doing is that we are trying to subtract the address of a[2] from the address of b[3] **

for every compilation the compiler will allocate different memory locations and so there cannot be specific output. but this code is always giving output as 5. even when I increased the number of elements in array 'a', the output is still same. why?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: "As far as my understanding, what we are doing is that we are trying to subtract the address of a[2] from the address of b[3]" in this case it's undefined behavior. "but this code is always giving output as 5." well compiler just choice to put the two array close together, that result doesn't help anyway.

Comment: The Undefined Behavior answers are correct but based on your info I am guessing that b[] has been placed 'before' a[] on the stack. Therefore changing the size of a[] has no effect. In  this *particular* example.

Comment: Subtracting `&a[2]` from `&b[3]` is like asking "How many houses do I go past walking from 4 Main St. to 10 Elm Ave.?".  Subtracting two house numbers on the same street makes sense, but when they're on different streets, it's a completely different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `-`, when applied to pointers, is defined only within the bounds of the respective (array) object beneath. As your arguments are of different arrays, the behaviour is undefined. If you observe the same values, it may be because the compiler will place one variable next to the other in memory, such that their relative distance might be the same in different runs. But this is not guaranteed, as it is actually undefined for the compiler how to behave.